# Understanding broadcast operation mpi

Tags: c, mpi

I have an MPI program that was given to us that receives an integer and double as input from the user and have the processes announce their value that they receive.

For example:

```
user input = 7 10.1
```

Output:

```
Process 1 got 7 and 10.100000
Process 2 got 7 and 10.100000
.
.
```

I understand that each process will just have to announce the values that was given by user input through a single broadcast but the code seemed complicated that i couldn't understand the logic of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rank; //rank of the process
   struct {int a;double b;} value;
   MPI_Datatype mystruct;
   int blocklens[2];   //what is this?
   MPI_Aint indices[2];   //what is this?
   MPI_Datatype oldtype[2];

   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); //initialize MPI environment
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

   blocklens[0] = 1;
   blocklens[1] = 1;

   oldtype[0] = MPI_INT;
   oldtype[1] = MPI_DOUBLE;

   MPI_Get_address(&value.a, &indices[0]);
   MPI_Get_address(&value.b, &indices[1]);

   indices[1] = indices[1] - indices[0];
   indices[0] = 0;
   MPI_Type_create_struct(2,blocklens,indices,oldtype,&mystruct);
   MPI_Type_commit(&mystruct);

   while (value.a >= 0) {
       if (rank == 0) {
           printf("Enter an integer and double: ");
           fflush(stdout);
           scanf("%d %lf",&value.a,&value.b);
       }
       MPI_Bcast(&value,1,mystruct,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
       printf("Process %d got %d and %lf\n",rank,value.a,value.b);
   }
   MPI_Type_free(&mystruct);
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
```

}

I would appreciate if someone could give me a run through of how the code works as i find it really hard to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

This code creates a MPI derived datatype so `struct value` can be broadcasted in a single MPI call.

This is IMHO a bad example since :

- the `offsetof()` macro should be used to (directly) populate the displacements array (`indices` is a very poor choice here)
- the predefined `MPI_DOUBLE_INT` datatype is a perfect fit (do not forget to swap `a` and `b` in the `struct value` definition)
- as a matter of taste, I’d rather recommend you pass the values via the command line rather than reading them from `stdin` (this is very subjective, and from experience, you will avoid surprises)